# In locust.io to get the endpoint from a testcase.json file

Tags: locust

Json file for endpoints
{
"endpoints": [
"endpoint1",
"endpoint2",
"endpoint3"
]
}
Python file

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.endpoints = self.load_endpoints_from_json("endpoints.json")

def load_endpoints_from_json(self, json_file):
    with open(json_file, "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return data.get("endpoints", [])
@task
    def mytask(self):
        for endpoint in self.endpoints:
            response = self.client.get(endpoint)
            if response.status_code == 200:
                logger.info(f"Request to {endpoint} successfully received", response)
            else:
                logger.error(f"Request to {endpoint} failed to receive", response)
```

I just need to get the status code along with the code

Comment: Your question is a little vague. Maybe try asking in the slack channel instead.